# How to properly call the SGEMV in Fortran?

Tags: visual-studio, fortran, blas, intel-fortran, intel-mkl

I want to perform a Matrix-Vector product in fortran using the SGEMV subroutine from BLAS.
I have a code that is similar to this:

```
program test
integer, parameter :: DP = selected_real_kind(15)
real(kind=DP), dimension (3,3) :: A
real(kind=DP), dimension (3) :: XP,YP
call sgemv(A,XP,YP)
```

A is a 3x3 Matrix, XP and YP are Vectors.
In the included module one can see the following code:

```
PURE SUBROUTINE SGEMV_F95(A,X,Y,ALPHA,BETA,TRANS)
    ! Fortran77 call:
    ! SGEMV(TRANS,M,N,ALPHA,A,LDA,X,INCX,BETA,Y,INCY)
    USE F95_PRECISION, ONLY: WP => SP
    REAL(WP), INTENT(IN), OPTIONAL :: ALPHA
    REAL(WP), INTENT(IN), OPTIONAL :: BETA
    CHARACTER(LEN=1), INTENT(IN), OPTIONAL :: TRANS
    REAL(WP), INTENT(IN) :: A(:,:)
    REAL(WP), INTENT(IN) :: X(:)
    REAL(WP), INTENT(INOUT) :: Y(:)
END SUBROUTINE SGEMV_F95
```

I understand that the some of the parameters are optional, so where am i wrong in the method call?

Comment: Please include the error messages that you get when trying to compile.

Comment: You show the interface for the subroutine `sgemv_f95` but `call sgemv`.  You also don't use any module.  So, and as the previous comment suggests, we need much more detail about your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you look at BLAS or LAPACK routines then you should always have a look at the first letter:

- `S`: single precision
- `D`: double precision
- `C`: single precision complex
- `Z`: double precision complex

You defined your matrix `A` as well as the vectors `XP` and `YP` as a double precision number using the statement:

```
integer, parameter :: DP = selected_real_kind(15)
```

So for this, you need to use `dgemv` or define your precision as single precision.

There is also a difference between calling `dgemv` and `dgemv_f95`. `dgemv_f95` is part of Intel MKL and not really a common naming. For portability reasons, I would not use that notation but stick to the classic `dgemv` which is also part of Intel MKL.

> `DGEMV`  performs one of the matrix-vector operations
>
> ```
> y := alpha*A*x + beta*y,   or   y := alpha*A**T*x + beta*y,
> ```
>
> where `alpha` and `beta` are scalars, `x` and `y` are vectors and `A` is an
>    `m` by `n` matrix.

If you want to know how to call the function, I suggest to have a look [here](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/dc/da8/dgemv_8f_source.html), but it should, in the end, look something like this:

```
call DGEMV('N',3,3,ALPHA,A,3,XP,1,BETA,YP,1)
```

Comment: Not only solved my issue, but helped me to understand better the BLAS routines. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The precisions are incompatible. You are calling `sgemv` which takes single precision arguments but you are passing double precision arrays and vectors.

Comment: Using a module can aid in ensuring the call is comparable. Is the module available?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the `trans` parameter is required?

```
trans: Must be 'N', 'C', or 'T'.
```

(As per the note at the bottom of [Developer Reference for Intel® Math Kernel Library - Fortran](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-fortran-gemv).)